# Что делает этот фрагмент кода c `sys.stdin`?

Tags: python

```
import sys
save_stdin=sys.stdin
sys.stdin=open("in/63.in")
#
#
sys.stdin = save_stdin
```

Comment: Вместо стандартного ввода будет использоваться файл.

Comment: Вопрос с собеседования? :)

Comment: @newman нет просто наткнулся на решение одной задачи, стало непонятно

Comment: related: [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4675728/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код  в вопросе временно перенаправляет стандартный ввод Питона из файла (`sys.stdin = save_stdin` восстанавливает старое значение).

Намерение кода эмулировать оператор `<` в командной строке (shell):

```
$ python ваш-скрипт.py < in/63.in
```

Ввод (`input()`, `for line in sys.stdin`, etc) читается из `63.in` файла, расположенного в дочерней (относительно текущей рабочей директории) `in` директории.

Присваивание `sys.stdin` не работает, если ввод читается на более низком уровне, например, когда Питон скрипт запускает дочерний процесс, который что-то читает из стандартного ввода ([вот пример кода, который показывает как перенаправить вывод (stdout) на уровне file descriptors, чтобы поддерживать и внешние процессы, C расширения и другой Питон код, который не пользуется высокоуровневым интерфейсом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22434262/4279)). Подобные вещи могут к неожиданным багам приводить (например, связанным с кэшом ввода), поэтому если есть возможность, то следует командную строчку изменить и не перенаправлять `sys.stdin` на уровне Питона.

Answer (score 3):

Это достаточно популярный **в олимпиадном программировании** (на это наталкивает `in` в пути и незакрытие файла) способ организации быстрого переключения (в исходном коде) ввода/вывода между **стандартными потоками** (известными, как `stdin` и `stdout`) и **файлами**.

Решение пишется с использованием `stdin`.

- Когда необходим ввод из файла, эти строчки нужно **раскомментировать**.
- Когда нужен сам `stdin`, их нужно **закомментировать**.

---

На практике, если выйти за рамки решения задачек и посмотреть на разработку программного обеспечения, так лучше не делать, поскольку стандартный поток может быть определён из оболочки (shell) ОС при запуске, без изменений в программе и файловой системе. Это более гибкий подход.

Такие строчки имеют смысл только в том случае, если система проверки задачи требует ввода и вывода из конкретных файлов. Во всех остальных случаях `stdin` удобнее:

- Если не направить потоки ввода из/в файлы, то при запуске программы будет интерактивная сессия, где можно ввести данные с клавиатуры.
- Если нужно проверить сразу несколько наборов входных данных, можно написать скриптик для оболочки (`*.bat`, `*.sh`, `*.bash`), который сам всё подставит на место `stdin` и `stdout` без необходимости менять программу.