# Перенаправление sys.stdout в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x

Работаю в Windows 7. В программе на Python 3 хочу весь консольный вывод перенаправить в файл. Соответственно нужно сделать как-то так:

```
sys.stdout = open('log.txt', 'w')
try:
    <do something>
finally:
    sys.stdout.close()
```

1. Правильно ли я закрываю этот поток?
2. Основная часть кода `<do something>` довольно объёмная, и мне неудобно работать с ней на первом уровне питоновской вложенности (табуляции). Т.б. внутри неё также встречаются уровни вложенности. Хочется сделать так, чтобы один раз в начале перенаправил поток, и потом если программа неожиданно вылетает поток пусть сам закроется. Можно это как-то сделать?
3. Если не закрыть поток перед выходом, есть ли шанс что часть данных не запишется?

UPD:

4. Можно ли **скопировать** поток вывода? Т.е. и в консоль, и в файл?

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4675728/4279)

Comment: 1- есть ли причины не использовать простой батничек с одной строчкой: `py ваш-скрипт.py > log.txt`? 2- `sys.stdout = open('log.txt', 'w')` не достаточно, чтобы весь вывод перенаправить. См. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22434262/4279) 3- Пожайлуйста, ограничивайтесь одной проблемой на вопрос (таким образом ваш вопрос более полезен для будущих посетителей), например, *"Можно ли скопировать поток вывода? Т.е. и в консоль, и в файл?"* лучше задать как новый вопрос (вы всегда можете добавить ссылку на текущий вопрос для контекста, если необходимо).

Comment: Ещё похожий вопрос: [Что делает этот фрагмент кода c `sys.stdin`?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/488836/181100)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше всего перенаправление осуществлять на уровне вызова вашего скрипта:

```
T:\> py ваш-скрипт.py > log.txt
```

Это гарантирует, что весь вывод направленный в stdout попадёт в log.txt.

`sys.stdout = open('log.txt', 'w')` этого не гарантирует, например, `os.system('echo мимо')` или `os.write(1, b'not to log.txt' + os.linesep.encode())` пишут в стандартный вывод напрямую вместо `log.txt` файла. Чтобы перехватить вывод на уровне file descriptors, можно использовать `os.dup2()`, см. [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22434262/4279)

Если вас интересует только вывод, который генерируется вызовами  `sys.stdout` методов, то `sys.stdout = open('log.txt', 'w')` достаточно (не нужны ни `try/finally`, ни `.close()`).

> Правильно ли я закрываю этот поток?

`.close()` это правильный способ закрыть файл в питоне. Можно использовать `with` конструкцию вместо `try/finally`:

```
with open('log.txt', 'w') as file, contextlib.redirect_stdout(file):
    ...
```

`file.close()` вызывается автоматически при выходе из `with` блока.

> Если не закрыть поток перед выходом, есть ли шанс что часть данных не запишется?

Питон сам закрывает `sys.stdout` при нормальном выходе (даже если есть непойманные исключения).  Поэтому обычно не нужно явно `sys.stdout` закрывать.

Если выход аварийный или если данные пишутся из разных потоков, то нужно обращать внимание на режим буферизации (`buffering`: 0, 1, или другое) и необходимо явно вызывать `.flush()`. Если хочется [гарантировать, что данные были записаны на диск, то всё сложнее (`os.fsync()`, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12003805/4279).

[`atexit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) поддерживает некоторые сценарии (например, `KeyboardInterrupt`). Можно `signal` модуль использовать, чтобы поддерживать другие необходимые сигналы (ограниченная полезность на Windows).

---

> Можно ли скопировать поток вывода? Т.е. и в консоль, и в файл?

Можно использовать `tee` утилиту:

```
PS T:\> py ваш-скрипт.py | tee log.txt
```

Данная команда сохраняет stdout в log.txt и печатает его в консоль.

Как обычно, на Windows, перенаправление может испортить данные, например, см. [Decode poweshell output possibly containing non-ascii unicode characters into a python string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33959798/4279).