# PyQt - не выводятся ошибки в консоль при нажатии на кнопку. Как отлаживать?

Tags: python, qt, исключения, pyqt5

**Суть проблемы:** создаю кнопку в окне программы, нажатие данной кнопки связываю с определенной функцией. Как это обычно бывает, функция содержит ошибки, которые убивают программу. Соответственно, при нажатии на кнопку, программа вылетает, но **в консоль не выводится причина ошибки и номер строки, где она допущена**.

**Пример:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Сгенерировать ошибку", self)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.make_exception())

    def make_exception(self):
        raise Exception("Я не увижу это сообщение")

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

При запуске кода выше и нажатии на кнопку, программа вылетит без объяснения причин.

[image: Скриншот работы]

**Вопрос:** почему сообщения об ошибках не выводятся в консоль и как это исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте библиотеку `traceback` чтобы обрабатывать исключения и выводить их на экран или консоль.

Пример вывода `traceback` на экран из за ошибки `label is not defined`

```
import traceback
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)

    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print(text)
    QtWidgets.QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)

    sys.exit()

sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Какой то текст")
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Нажми")
        button.clicked.connect(self.func)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        lay.addWidget(label)
        lay.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(lay)

    def func(self):
        label.setText('Привет')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и на примере вашего кода

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А Вы не в курсе, почему так происходит? В чем причина того, что сообщение не выводится?

Comment: @АртемПоликарпов попробуйте python из cmd.exe запустить (Windows console). Возможно ошибки печатаются напрямую в Си stderr в обход `sys.stderr`. Для проверки, видите ли вы вывод `os.write(2, b'abc\n')`? См. [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22434262/4279)

Comment: В GUI приложении вообще не следует на std* потоки полагаться (их может не быть: `*.pyw`).  То есть подход в ответе правильный (перехватить все необработанные исключения и действие специфичное для приложения выполнить). Это может быть недостаточно, если какие-то части (типа Qt, пытаются мусорить в Си stderr). В этом случае можно попробовать перенаправить Сишный вывод как по ссылке выше показано. На русском нашёл ссылку: [Перенаправление sys.stdout в файл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/495848/23044)